# App crashes on back button / Activities & Intents

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an android application which starts a new activity

```
Intent startAuthorization = new Intent(AndroidActivity, AuthorizeUser.class);       
startActivityForResult(startAuthorization,4711);
```

When that new activity is done (a ok button is clicked) I call

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnResult);
finish();
```

Which works fine. In case the user doesn't click the okay button but uses the return button of the phone (this arrow pointing around to the left) the application has a force close. I have set a breakpoint on the first line of my method onActivityResult but the debugger never stops there. I have no idea where the issue comes up - how can I find out? Is there a method I have to overwrite to handle this back button?

Comment: Could you paste the logcat output of the moment your app is crashing? 
There should be a Java Exception showing us some more details on why your app is force closing.

Comment: the method to overwrite the behaviour of the back button is called onBackPressed(). My suspicion is that your previous activity gets destroyed and when you you press back you don't have that activity on the stack but a null pointer which causes the crash. Some logs would be helpful though. This is the official description of the onBackPressed() at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()

Answer (score 1):

try this if you don't find any better solution for your problem.
overwrite the onKeyDown event to prevent your app from going back when you press back button

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent msg){
    if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) || (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
        || (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CALL))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```